# Typescript compiler allowing duplicate type declarations

Tags: typescript

I have two types X. One declared in the file, the other one imported.
When i use this type X to declare a variable, the compiler assumes the imported type.

file1.ts

```
export type X = number
```

file2.ts

```
import { X } from "./file2"

export type X = string
export const x: X = "foo" //this causes a compilation error
export const x: X = 42 //this works just fine
```

I have noticed that this only happens if the local type is exported. If it is not exported, you will see a conflict error on the import.

Is this expected behaviour or is this a bug in the tsc?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest avoiding shadowing your import/export names altogether using a simple alias, so that

`import { X } from "./file1"`

becomes

`import { X as IWillNotShadowModulesAgain } from "./file1"`

This way you will be able to use both declarations in the same file like

```js
import { X as IWillNotShadowModulesAgain } from "./file2"
export type X = string;

const a:IWillNotShadowModulesAgain = 12;
const b:X = 'IPromise';
```

Comment: Thanks Luca, that is the solution I used. The question here is not about how to solve the problem, but more about why the compiler is allowing me to do this in the first place.

Comment: Well, it's not uncommon to have the same names for different modules, especially in your dependencies. For example, you have a `Response` class defined in the default http library and in Express. Typescript does not prevent you from using both but it would be really hard to understand which one you want to use based upon the context of your file, so it leaves to the programmer the responsibility to handle them correctly. Mind that this is only allowed with modules, you have already noticed yourself that if you do not export the second declaration you receive an error.